# Atualizar o echo em uma pagina a cada minuto

Tags: php, data, time, echo

Estou exibindo a hora no painel do usuário com o código:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$date = date('d-m-Y H:i');
?>
```

Através do comando echo:

```
<?php
  require("includes/serverTime.php");
  echo "<div class=\"date\">BR, $date</div>";
```

Acontece que a hora exibida só muda se eu apertar f5.
Se eu não apertar f5 ela fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem alguma forma de eu fazer esse echo atualizar a cada minuto?

Comment: Talvez a melhor solução seja usar javascript. Com php, vai ter que atualizar toda hora mesmo.

Comment: Se não quiser usar javascript (mas não tem nenhum vantagem em fazer isso), põe essa hora dentro de um iframe e no head dessa página do iframe tu usa uma meta refresh.
Mas o legal é com javscript mesmo, que aí vai contando os segundos também, fica dinâmico. Muito melhor que com php apenas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caso queira fazer com **Jquery** faça assim:

```js
$(function() {
  var data_hora = document.getElementById("data_hora");
  window.setInterval(function(){
     var now = new Date
     data_hora.innerHTML = "BR, " + now.getDay() + "/" + now.getDate() + "/" + now.getMonth() + "   " + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
  },5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="data_hora"></p>
```

Usei a função `setInterval` que executa uma função que é passada para ela no primeiro parâmetro e como segundo parâmetro o tempo em segundos para que ela execute a função.

Comment: Apesar de ser uma pagina em php, o que fará a pagina atualizar não é o php, e sim esse comando do header do html que você inseriu, logo, não é bem uma solução **somente** em php.

Comment: É verdade @DiegoF erro meu vou deixar só a parte com Jquery caso sirva para ele!

Answer (score 2):

PHP não da refresh na página então Você pode inicializar seu javascript com a data do servidor:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
?>
<div class="date">BR, <span id="server_time"></span></div>
<script>
    var server_time = document.getElementById("server_time");
    var now = new Date(<?=date('Y')?>, <?=date('m')-1?>, <?=date('d')?>, <?=date('H')?>, <?=date('i')?>, <?=date('s')?>, 0);
    window.setInterval(function(){
        now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 1);
        server_time.innerHTML = now.getDate() + "/" + (now.getMonth() + 1 )+ "/" + now.getFullYear() +  "   " + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
    },1000);
</script>
```

Por que eu não botei a data dentro do new Date(), porque o que funciona no chrome não funciona firefox, nesse caso sempre vai funcionar em ambos.
Você pode melhorar o código para mostrar 0, assim ficaria 03:03:03 e não 3:3:3.

Comment: Por favor me ajude a converter as horas para mostrar o 0 ficando: 03:03:03 e não 3:3:3.
Estou tentando fazer com PHP mas não estou conseguindo.
O que você me aconselha?